# Replacing an array column of ids with an array of the records - SQL

Tags: postgresql

Let's ignore the database design - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180638/sql-replacing-an-array-column-of-ids-with-an-array-of-the-records. I'm more just curious if this is possible. I have a table called orders with a column of products. In this column is an array with the ids of all the products that are in the order. Is it possible for me to query for the products and replace the products column with the result? This is what I have so far, but errors for having too many columns on the subquery.

`SELECT o.*, ( SELECT p.* FROM products p WHERE p.id = ANY(o.products::int[])) products FROM orders o`

Order's Table:

```
ID      Products   Status    Total
1       [1,2,5]    1         4
2       [1,3,5]    1         5
3       [1,3,6]    1         5
```

Products Table:

```
ID      Name              Price
1       Blue shoe         1
2       Red Shoe          1 
3       Green Shoes       2
4       Purple Shoe       1
5       Orange Shoes      2
6       Pink Shoes        2
```

Desired Output - selecting the first order.

```
{
  ID:1,
  Products:[ <Products Record-1>, <Products Record-2>, <Products Record-5>
           ],
  Status: 1,
  Total: 4
}
```

Comment: Are the products in a given order stored in CSV format and do you want to overwrite this CSV data with something else?  Can you show us sample data?

Comment: Updated. No this wouldn't being using a CSV. This is for an API

Comment: There _might_ be a way to do this using JSON functions in MySQL, but why don't you just build the JSON in your app layer?

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, I was just curious if it was possible without doing so. FWIW I'm using Postgres but I rode a down vote train using the 'postgres' tag. I was told that using these tags 'mysql and sqlite' would be more helpful

Comment: `I was told that using these tags ... would be more helpful` ... not really helpful, but more wasteful of people's time, and more confusing.

Comment: Uhhh, okay. Well thanks for looking over it

Comment: Now that you have the real tag, I upvoted your question.  You could probably do this with a custom function in Postgres.  There are a few folks on the site who can help you, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for doing that. I chose the tags as maybe there was a universal way of doing it - independent of which rdbms one was using.

Comment: Quite the contrary, JSON support is probably the area which is most different across databases.  But lucky for you, Postgres has good JSON support.